# How to remove dependencies form being included in the Karma test coverage

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine, test-coverage

Karma allows you see the test coverage using karma conf file

```
reporters
Type: Array
Default: ['progress']
CLI: --reporters progress,growl
Possible Values:
dots
progress
junit
growl
coverage
Description: A list of reporters to use.
```

The issue I am having is that it includes dependencies in the test coverage. How can I exclude those from the test coverage as I do not want to test certain files.

Answer (score 1):

The `coverage`'s `preprocessors` attribute takes a file spec.

My project scructure is:

```
/js/
/lib/
/tests/
```

See line 4 here where I instruct `coverage` to process only `js/**/*.js`. If I did not do that it would also include my `lib/` and my `tests/` folders.

```
coverage: {
  reporters: ['spec', 'coverage'],
  preprocessors: {
    'js/**/*.js': ['coverage']
  },
  coverageReporter: {
    reporters: [
      { type: 'text' },
      { type: 'html', dir: 'coverage/' }
    ]
  }
}
```